# How is the fundamental matrix (in computer vision) derived?

Tags: matrix-equations

In [this paper](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0004370295000224/1-s2.0-0004370295000224-main.pdf?_tid=db9b304e-31d6-11e7-8c56-00000aab0f26&acdnat=1494018633_a90ea0cc8a6e9ec7c1e0a9f89bc21a4e), page 92, the so called fundamental matrix in computer vision is derived.

Some notation:

$M = (x,y,z)^T$ is a 3d point and $
\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      M\\
      1
    \end{array}
\right] 
$ represents the homogeneous coordinate $(x,y,z,1)^T$

There are two pinhole cameras defined as:

$P_i$ a 3x4 projection matrix for camera $i$:

$$m_i = P_i \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      M\\
      1
    \end{array}
\right] 
= s_i \left[ 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      u_i\\
      v_i\\
      1
    \end{array}
\right]$$

The projection can be decomposed into $A_i\left[R_i\ t_i\right]$, where $A_i$ are the intrinsic parameters of the camera (an upper 3x3 triangular matrix), $R_i$ is a 3x3 rotation matrix (rotates the camera relative to the coordinate systems axises), and $t_i$ is a 3x1 translation vector. Note: $\left[R_i\ t_i\right]$ is a 3x4 matrix ($t$ is the last column).

$A_i$ defines the camera intrinsic parameters (focal length, scale factors, etc) I don't think these parameters are relevant to my question ,but the matrix looks like this:

$$
A_i = \begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\0&d&e\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$

The first camera ($i=1$) is positioned at origo and its axises aligns with the coordinate axises:

$$P_1 = A_1 \left[I\ \Bbb{0} \right]$$

The second camera is translated by $t$ and rotated by $R$ and has its own intrinsic parameters $A_2$:

$$P_2 = A_2\left[R\ t \right]$$

With these notations, we have the following two equations to project the 3d point $M$ to the plane of each camera:

$$
s_1m_1 = A_1[I\ 0] \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      M\\
      1
    \end{array}
\right] 
\tag{1}
$$
$$
s_2m_2 = A_2[R\ t] \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      M\\
      1
    \end{array}
\right] 
\tag{2}
$$

**Epipolar geometry**

Given two images from two different cameras of the same scene, a ray from the camera center to a point $M$ will project as a line in each camera plane. $M$ is projected to $m_1$. There is a line $l_{m_1}$ in the other camera plane in which $m_2$ must be on. This line is called the epipolar line.

An image explains it better:

[image]

So if we know $m_1$, and we need to find $m_2$ (the corresponding point to $m_1$), then we could limit the search to the epipolar line $l_2$ (which goes through $e_2$ and $m_2$). In this way, we can search in one dimension instead of two for the corresponding points in the other camera image. Of course we cannot find $l_2$ via $m_2$ since we are looking for $m_2$.

The fundamental matrix $F$ is defined such that: $l_2 = F\ m_1$. And the constraint that $m_2$ will be on this line is: $m_2^T l_2 = 0$.

So the constraint to find $F$ is: $m_2^T F m_1 = 0$.

Unfortunately I'm not able to see (neither geometrically nor algebraically) how $F$ is derived / deduced.

**Question**

From these two equations, in the paper (and I've seen it in other papers as well), the following is deduced (which proofs the existence of $F$):

$$ m_2^{T}A_2^{-T}TRA_1^{-1}m_1= 0 $$

with the note: "by eliminating $M$, $s1$ and $s2$", and: $T$ is an antisymmetric matrix defined by $t$ such that, where $\times$ is the cross product, $Tx = t \times x$ for all 3D vectors.

How exactly can these be eliminated given (1) and (2)?

I thought I could eliminate $M$ this way:

$
A_2^{-1}s_2m_2 = RM+t
$

$RA_1^{-1}s_1m_1 + t = RM+t$

$RA_1^{-1}s_1m_1 + t = A_2^{-1}s_2m_2$

At this point, I suppose T is used since $Tt$ would be $t$ cross $t$ which is zero.

$TRA_1^{-1}s_1m_1 = TA_2^{-1}s_2m_2$

Thankful for a hint or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. From equations (1) and (2), we have $s_1A_1^{-1}\tilde{\mathbf m}_1 = M$ and $s_2A_2^{-1}\tilde{\mathbf m}_2 = RM + \mathbf t = s_1RA_1^{-1}\tilde{\mathbf m}_1 + \mathbf t$. The cross product of two vectors is orthogonal to them both, so we have $$\begin{align} 0 = (s_2A_2^{-1}\tilde{\mathbf m}_2)^T(\mathbf t\wedge s_2A_2^{-1}\tilde{\mathbf m}_2) &= (s_2A_2^{-1}\tilde{\mathbf m}_2)^T(\mathbf t\wedge(s_1RA_1^{-1}\tilde{\mathbf m}_1 + \mathbf t)) \\
&= (s_2A_2^{-1}\tilde{\mathbf m}_2)^T(\mathbf t\wedge s_1RA_1^{-1}\tilde{\mathbf m}_1 + \mathbf t\wedge\mathbf t) \\
&= (s_2A_2^{-1}\tilde{\mathbf m}_2)^T(\mathbf t\wedge s_1RA_1^{-1}\tilde{\mathbf m}_1) \\
&= s_1s_2(A_2^{-1}\tilde{\mathbf m}_2)^T(\mathbf t\wedge RA_1^{-1}\tilde{\mathbf m}_1) \\
&= s_1s_2\tilde{\mathbf m}_2^T(A_2^{-1})^T TRA_1^{-1}\tilde{\mathbf m}_1.\end{align}$$ We now drop the irrelevant scale factors and are left with the desired equation.

Comment: Thanks! It is interesting to note that there is a degenerate case where RM is in the same direction as t. Which could happen if the two cameras are somewhat facing each other and M lies between the two cameras.

Comment: @j-a When $M$, $C_1$ and $C_2$ are colinear, you don’t have a unique plane. The resulting fundamental matrix will be rank-deficient, I believe.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks!

Comment: I can’t help feeling that this derivation is a bit contrived. Seems like there should be a way to derive this same equation from the condition that $C_1$, $C_2$, $m_1$ and $m_2$ are coplanar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems helpful to note that for any pair of vectors $x,y$ on $3$ components, we have
$$
x^T[m_2^{T}A_2^{-T}TRA_1^{-1}m_1]y = \\
(A_2^{-1}m_2 x)^T(TRA^{-1}m_1y) = \\
(A_2^{-1}m_2 x)^T(t \times [RA^{-1}m_1y])
$$
It would be sufficient to prove that the image of $A_2^{-1}m_2$ lies in the plane spanned by $t$ and the image of $RA^{-1} m_1$, assuming that I've interpreted the data types here correctly.

Comment: I see you are starting from the result, to prove that it is true. That will also give me insights thanks. A^-1m_1 = M, so RA^-1m_1 is RM. But what would RMy be? Geometrically it is true that these must lie in the same plane. (RM+t, t, RM), somewhat confused by (RM+t, t, RMy) though? Why is x and y required to make the proof? (Would also appreciate any hint on how to go from the first two equations to end up with the result).

Comment: It is often convenient to show that a matrix $M$ is zero by showing that $x^TMy$ is zero for every $x$ and $y$. See my latest edit; that should be the "the image of $RA^{-1}m_1$".

Comment: Honestly, it's really hard for me to follow how you've defined all of the matrices here.  It is not clear to me, for example, that we should have $A_2^{-1}m_2 = M$.  Given that I can't understand what the pieces are, I can't tell you how to go from the equations through the proof.

Comment: Thanks for answering I will update the question and try clarify everything to the best of my understanding

Comment: I updated the question, is it a bit better now?